# How to encrypt with LUKS a live Ubuntu usb stick that has been customized with Cubic?

Tags: encryption, ubuntu, luks, boot

I'm using Cubic (https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic) to create a custom Ubuntu. So far so good, everything is going smoothly.
However, I would like to encrypt the USB stick that contains my custom Ubuntu image so that I:

- boot usb (load bootloader and grub which are not encrypted)
- decrypt the OS with a password
- login to my custom Ubuntu normally

Please note that the custom Ubuntu will be loaded into RAM every time. I don't want any persistence so installing Ubuntu directly to the usb stick is not an option for me.

P.S. I have found this thread from 3 years ago https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2424061 I'm trying to do the same but what OP was asking has been left unanswered.

It has also been asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162410/how-to-create-live-usb-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks but the answers are incorrect because is possible if the boot volume is unencrypted.